Extract a hierarchical topology from stream network
A typical stream network has a hierarchical topology that resembles a cladogram (phylogenetic tree). There are many software tools that have been developed to analyze variables along a cladogram, which could be easily adapted to analyze a stream network. We can manually construct a tree file from small stream networks using the hierarchy inferred from USGS HUCs, but the workload scales exponentially with watershed area.
Are there any tools that extract (or convert) a stream topology into a cladogram file format (.newick, .tree, .phylip, etc.)?

Well, it only resembles a cladogram if topography (where are things) is of no concern - tributary volume diagrams or other purely scalar visualizations - but I do like the idea of 'misusing' that kind of software. Is any of those file formats Open Source and can easily be created programmatically, without heavy reverse engineering effort (e.g. XML based)? That would probably be your best bet for a manual export. However, GIS software does have its own set of tools for stream network analysis, you may want to dig into that a little.

Thank you, @geozelot! Yes the formats are open source, one of them is nexml, which is adapted from xml. My original attempt to infer a dendrogram using network distance was a failure, because network distances are not 1:1 to topological "distance." You may have pointed this out above (just now getting back to this forum).  Are you aware of a tool in Network Analysist (Arc or Q) that exports the network in xml format?
